# Intel E7500 OS supports

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cpu, operating-systems, 32-bit

I have an Intel E7500 processor on a HP Compaq 6000 Pro MT PC. Processor info in msinfo32.exe shows this:

> Processor  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz, 2933 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

and as System Type shows this:

> System Type    X86-based PC

Does that mean that my pc only supports 32bit OS? Or can I install also 64bit OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install x64

Official link have detailed description.  http://ark.intel.com/products/36503/ As per this, it supports 64 bit architecture. So yes, you can!

Comment: Please read guidelines before attempt to answer. Welcome to StackExchange.